# Netbeans freeze on background scanning with NPM / Grunt

Tags: netbeans, gruntjs, npm

I have Grunt installed with and some tasks loaded.

When I open Netbeans, it starts `background scanning` and freeze for a while (from 15s to 2 min). 
This happens too when I install new npm modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to exclude `node_modules` from your netbeans' project.

1. Right click on your project in projects' tab.
2. Click on `Properties`
3. Go to `Ignored folders`
4. Click on `Add folders`
5. Add `node_modules`
6. Save config and restart Netbeans

Note that you can add folders to ignore while creating project.

Comment: Is this the way it should always be setup?  Do you loose any code completion features by doing this? Thanks!

Comment: You could loose some completion feature if you're working with Netbeans inside `node_modules`. But if you're just using NPM / Grunt and not developping anything, it's the right way.

Comment: Thanks very much. It seems in V8 this has changed, do you know about that?

Comment: I see that when using the HTML5 project type there is no Ignore Folders option, this is reported as a enhancement request here: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=238709